# Syntax error: variable used as value, for loop in Go

Tags: loops, go

I'm totally new to Go and am going through https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/8

I've tried the following for loop (whether it actually solves the problem posed by the page is irrelevant, I'm only interested in the syntax here). You can assume `z` and `x` are given:

```
for z < x; z -= (z*z - x) / (2*z) {
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

I get the following error when I try to run:

`./prog.go:9:36: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting semicolon or newline
./prog.go:10:17: syntax error: z -= (z * z - x) / (2 * z) used as value`

I can get rid of the first error by changing the loop to this:

```
for z < x; z -= (z*z - x) / (2*z); {
    fmt.Println(z)
}
```

But I still get the second error.

Comment: `for ; z < x; z -= (z*z - x) / (2*z) {}`. [Spec: For statements](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements). You either use a single condition, or with for clause you have 3 parts: init statement (which in your case is empty), condition and post statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop should be like this

`for ;z < x; z -= (z*z - x) / (2*z) {
    fmt.Println(z)
}`

*;* Should appear before the z < x condition this is because ,
The syntax of for loop is for [control var] ; [condition] ; [iterate] { //body }

Just a single *;* can be used as a null statement hence by using it we provide the for loop all the required parameters.
 `; x < z; x++` as you can see aside the first semicolon indicates empty/null statement ( as we don't set any variable ) , the second is condition and the third is the iteration command.

Now you can clearly understand that in your second approach 
`z < x; z -= (z*z - x) / (2*z);` z < x is the control variable , which causes the error as ( z < x ) is not a variable . The cause of *Error* is z -=( z*z-x)/(2*z)  is considered as the condition value , since this is not a value rather a statement an error is thrown.

Hope you understand...